# Microsoft Graph API conversation Id changed after i replied to first message of thread

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

We are creating Microsoft graph API conversation. When I create message I get message Id and conversation Id which I save in to my database.

After this other members reply to my message and whole thread is being created.

When I fetch messages with filter('conversation Id' eq 'someId') , I get whole thread.

Issue arises when I fetch whole Inbox, then all these replies to my first message has different conversation Id.

Is there any way to keep conversation Id same across whole thread after replies from other members?

Comment: Initially please recheck if you are checking ConversationId of the replies , because there is this message Id which is different and varies for each reply.Please check if there is any change in the identifier format of conversationId  of the replies,try changing to base64encoded .Also check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id)

Comment: Actually last 26 characters of conversation Id is same across all user replies when they fetch inbox emails. Message Id is different I know so I do not want to rely on it.
Unfortunately conversation Id is not supported by immutable-id